# Why are the methods groups allowed on the left-side of ‘is’ operator and how can this be used in practice?

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

First of all “A method group is a set of overloaded methods resulting from a member lookup”. In my example I use the set of `Console.WriteLine` methods with 19 overloads.

The definition of a method group in C# Language Specification also states that: “A method group is permitted in an invocation-expression (§7.6.5) , a delegate-creation-expression (§7.6.10.5) **and as the left hand side of an is operator**, and can be implicitly converted to a compatible delegate type (§6.6).”

I could think of one scenario where this functionality could be useful:

```
Action<string> print = (Action<string>)Console.WriteLine;
print("Hello!");

if (Console.WriteLine is Action<string>) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("We're compatible!");
}
```

First couple of lines show that we can ‘cast’ a method group `Console.WriteLine` into a delegate. What actually happens is the “implicit conversion converted to a compatible delegate type”, which creates an instance of a delegate calling one of many overloaded `Console.WriteLine` methods with compatible signature.

So according to specs we could use the “left side of is operator” feature mentioned above to test if the method group is compatible with a given delegate type (implicit conversion exists). This is what is checked inside the ‘if’ statement in the sample code.

Surprisingly, the code compiles, but gives a warning *“The given expression is never of the provided ('System.Action') type”*. So it looks like there will be no attempts to check the compatibility of the method group and the delegate type at runtime.

Hence, my questions:

- Why are the methods groups allowed on the left-side of ‘is’ operator if the check cannot be performed at runtime?
- Why this construct gives a warning and not a compilation error?
- Are there any practical scenarios of using method groups on the left side of ‘is’ operator?
- Is this something reserved for future uses, i.e. it is envisaged that the code above will work someday?

Comment: @Eric Lippert already wrote in "The C# Programming Language" book: "That a method group is legal on the left-hand side of an `is` operator is a bit of misleading feature. The result of the `is` evaluation will always be `false`, even if the method group *is* convertible to the type on the right hand-side". See https://books.google.co.il/books?id=s-IH_x6ytuQC&lpg=PT336&ots=ls909TgS6V&pg=PT336#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification (4.0) explicitly calls out this specific case:

> 7.10.10 The `is` operator
>
> [...] The result of the operation `E is T` where `E` is an expression and `T` is a type, is a boolean value [...]

So far, so good.  The specification continues:

> If `E` is a method group [...] the result is false.

Given this information, let's look at your questions.

> Why are the methods groups allowed on the left-side of ‘is’ operator if the check cannot be performed at runtime?

The specification allows for this operation.  See [Lippert's answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3232063/5240004) about how this came to be.

> Why this construct gives a warning and not a compilation error?

The construct is syntactically valid, even though it always evaluates to false.  The warning is just there to let you know that you may be doing something unintended.

> Are there any practical scenarios of using method groups on the left side of ‘is’ operator?

Probably not.  Maybe if you were passed an `object` that may be a method group or may be something else this construct *could* be useful. (It's admittedly a contrived example, that represents some seriously questionable practices.)

> Is this something reserved for future uses, i.e. it is envisaged that the code above will work someday?

No. Quoting again from Lippert "it *would* be a breaking change to make 'M is D' suddenly start returning true or being an error." [Emphasis in original]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the link to Eric Lippert's comment on this issue. If I could find it myself I would not ask this question.